# WAF blocks http requests with POST data containing a space and the word ON

Tags: amazon-web-services

We are experiencing issues with WAF enabled when HTTP requests to an Elastic Load Balancer get blocked if the POST formdata of those requests contains the word "ON" preceded by a space.

Comment: Have you checked the cloudwatch WAF logs?

Comment: When you say "formdata" do you meam `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?  If so, do you mean that you are posting a form that is somehow being created with a space that isn't encoded in the body as `+`?